# "TypeError: expected string or buffer" when attempting to parse JSON using python

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python & Json processing. I am using Python 2.7. I get several error messages When i execute the following code:

```
import os
import ast
import json

tweets={}
with open('C:\Python27\Test data\json\companies1.json','r') as input_file:
     tweets = json.loads(input_file)
     print  tweets.keys()
     print "\n"
```

Error message is below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/afurxr3/PycharmProjects/Coudera/LargeJSON.py", line 13, in <module>
 tweets = json.loads(input_file)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
 TypeError: expected string or buffer

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't get any errors when i execute the following code but some of intial Json keys are missing:

```
  import os
  import ast
  import json

 tweets=[]
 for line in open('C:\Python27\Test data\json\companies1.json','r'):
       tweets.append(json.loads(line))
       print (json.dumps(tweets,indent=4))
       print "\n"
```

My Json input file is below:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8a" }, "name" : "Wetpaint", "permalink" : "abc2", "crunchbase_url" : "http://www.crunchbase.com/company/wetpaint", "homepage_url" : "http://wetpaint-inc.com", "blog_url" : "http://digitalquarters.net/", "blog_feed_url" : "http://digitalquarters.net/feed/", "twitter_username" : "BachelrWetpaint", "category_code" : "web", "number_of_employees" : 47, "founded_year" : 2005, "founded_month" : 10, "founded_day" : 17, "deadpooled_year" : 1, "tag_list" : "wiki, seattle, elowitz, media-industry, media-platform, social-distribution-system", "alias_list" : "", "email_address" : "info@wetpaint.com", "phone_number" : "206.859.6300", "description" : "Technology Platform Company", "created_at" : { "$date" : 1180075887000 }, "updated_at" : "Sun Dec 08 07:15:44 UTC 2013", "overview" : "<p>Wetpaint is a technology platform company that uses its proprietary state-of-the-art technology and expertise in social media to build and monetize audiences for digital publishers. Wetpaint’s own online property, Wetpaint Entertainment, an entertainment news site that attracts more than 12 million unique visitors monthly and has over 2 million Facebook fans, is a proof point to the company’s success in building and engaging audiences. Media companies can license Wetpaint’s platform which includes a dynamic playbook tailored to their individual needs and comprehensive training. Founded by Internet pioneer Ben Elowitz, and with offices in New York and Seattle, Wetpaint is backed by Accel Partners, the investors behind Facebook.</p>", "image" : { "available_sizes" : [ [ [ 150, 75 ], "assets/images/resized/0000/3604/3604v14-max-150x150.jpg" ], [ [ 250, 125 ], "assets/images/resized/0000/3604/3604v14-max-250x250.jpg" ], [ [ 450, 225 ], "assets/images/resized/0000/3604/3604v14-max-450x450.jpg" ] ] }, "products" : [ { "name" : "Wikison Wetpaint", "permalink" : "wetpaint-wiki" }, { "name" : "Wetpaint Social Distribution System", "permalink" : "wetpaint-social-distribution-system" } ], "relationships" : [ { "is_past" : false, "title" : "Co-Founder and VP, Social and Audience Development", "person" : { "first_name" : "Michael", "last_name" : "Howell", "permalink" : "michael-howell" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "Co-Founder/CEO/Board of Directors", "person" : { "first_name" : "Ben", "last_name" : "Elowitz", "permalink" : "ben-elowitz" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "COO/Board of Directors", "person" : { "first_name" : "Rob", "last_name" : "Grady", "permalink" : "rob-grady" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "SVP, Strategy and Business Development", "person" : { "first_name" : "Chris", "last_name" : "Kollas", "permalink" : "chris-kollas" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "Board", "person" : { "first_name" : "Theresia", "last_name" : "Ranzetta", "permalink" : "theresia-ranzetta" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "Board Member", "person" : { "first_name" : "Gus", "last_name" : "Tai", "permalink" : "gus-tai" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "Board", "person" : { "first_name" : "Len", "last_name" : "Jordan", "permalink" : "len-jordan" } }, { "is_past" : false, "title" : "Head of Technology and Product", "person" : { "first_name" : "Alex", "last_name" : "Weinstein", "permalink" : "alex-weinstein" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "CFO", "person" : { "first_name" : "Bert", "last_name" : "Hogue", "permalink" : "bert-hogue" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "CFO/ CRO", "person" : { "first_name" : "Brian", "last_name" : "Watkins", "permalink" : "brian-watkins" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "Senior Vice President, Marketing", "person" : { "first_name" : "Rob", "last_name" : "Grady", "permalink" : "rob-grady" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "VP, Technology and Product", "person" : { "first_name" : "Werner", "last_name" : "Koepf", "permalink" : "werner-koepf" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "VP Marketing", "person" : { "first_name" : "Kevin", "last_name" : "Flaherty", "permalink" : "kevin-flaherty" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "VP User Experience", "person" : { "first_name" : "Alex", "last_name" : "Berg", "permalink" : "alex-berg" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "VP Engineering", "person" : { "first_name" : "Steve", "last_name" : "McQuade", "permalink" : "steve-mcquade" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "Executive Editor", "person" : { "first_name" : "Susan", "last_name" : "Mulcahy", "permalink" : "susan-mulcahy" } }, { "is_past" : true, "title" : "VP Business Development", "person" : { "first_name" : "Chris", "last_name" : "Kollas", "permalink" : "chris-kollas" } } ], "competitions" : [ { "competitor" : { "name" : "Wikia", "permalink" : "wikia" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "JotSpot", "permalink" : "jotspot" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "Socialtext", "permalink" : "socialtext" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "Ning by Glam Media", "permalink" : "ning" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "Soceeo", "permalink" : "soceeo" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "Yola", "permalink" : "yola" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "SocialGO", "permalink" : "socialgo" } }, { "competitor" : { "name" : "IslamNor", "permalink" : "islamnor" } } ], "providerships" : [], "total_money_raised" : "$39.8M", "funding_rounds" : [ { "id" : 888, "round_code" : "a", "source_url" : "http://seattlepi.nwsource.com/business/246734_wiki02.html", "source_description" : "", "raised_amount" : 5250000, "raised_currency_code" : "USD", "funded_year" : 2005, "funded_month" : 10, "funded_day" : 1, "investments" : [ { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Frazier Technology Ventures", "permalink" : "frazier-technology-ventures" }, "person" : null }, { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Trinity Ventures", "permalink" : "trinity-ventures" }, "person" : null } ] }, { "id" : 889, "round_code" : "b", "source_url" : "http://pulse2.com/2007/01/09/wiki-builder-website-wetpaint-welcomes-95m-funding/", "source_description" : "", "raised_amount" : 9500000, "raised_currency_code" : "USD", "funded_year" : 2007, "funded_month" : 1, "funded_day" : 1, "investments" : [ { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Accel Partners", "permalink" : "accel-partners" }, "person" : null }, { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Frazier Technology Ventures", "permalink" : "frazier-technology-ventures" }, "person" : null }, { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Trinity Ventures", "permalink" : "trinity-ventures" }, "person" : null } ] }, { "id" : 2312, "round_code" : "c", "source_url" : "http://www.accel.com/news/news_one_up.php?news_id=185", "source_description" : "Accel", "raised_amount" : 25000000, "raised_currency_code" : "USD", "funded_year" : 2008, "funded_month" : 5, "funded_day" : 19, "investments" : [ { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "DAG Ventures", "permalink" : "dag-ventures" }, "person" : null }, { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Accel Partners", "permalink" : "accel-partners" }, "person" : null }, { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Trinity Ventures", "permalink" : "trinity-ventures" }, "person" : null }, { "company" : null, "financial_org" : { "name" : "Frazier Technology Ventures", "permalink" : "frazier-technology-ventures" }, "person" : null } ] } ], "investments" : [], "acquisition" : { "price_amount" : 30000000, "price_currency_code" : "USD", "term_code" : "cash_and_stock", "source_url" : "http://allthingsd.com/20131216/viggle-tries-to-bulk-up-its-social-tv-business-by-buying-wetpaint/?mod=atdtweet", "source_description" : " Viggle Tries to Bulk Up Its Social TV Business by Buying Wetpaint", "acquired_year" : 2013, "acquired_month" : 12, "acquired_day" : 16, "acquiring_company" : { "name" : "Viggle", "permalink" : "viggle" } }, "acquisitions" : [], "offices" : [ { "description" : "", "address1" : "710 - 2nd Avenue", "address2" : "Suite 1100", "zip_code" : "98104", "city" : "Seattle", "state_code" : "WA", "country_code" : "USA", "latitude" : 47.603122, "longitude" : -122.333253 }, { "description" : "", "address1" : "270 Lafayette Street", "address2" : "Suite 505", "zip_code" : "10012", "city" : "New York", "state_code" : "NY", "country_code" : "USA", "latitude" : 40.7237306, "longitude" : -73.9964312 } ], "milestones" : [ { "id" : 5869, "description" : "Wetpaint named in Lead411's Hottest Seattle Companies list", "stoned_year" : 2010, "stoned_month" : 6, "stoned_day" : 8, "source_url" : "http://www.lead411.com/seattle-companies.html", "source_text" : null, "source_description" : "LEAD411 LAUNCHES \"HOTTEST SEATTLE COMPANIES\" AWARDS", "stoneable_type" : "Company", "stoned_value" : null, "stoned_value_type" : null, "stoned_acquirer" : null, "stoneable" : { "name" : "Wetpaint", "permalink" : "wetpaint" } }, { "id" : 8702, "description" : "Site-Builder Wetpaint Makes One For Itself, Using the Demand Media Playbook", "stoned_year" : 2010, "stoned_month" : 9, "stoned_day" : 6, "source_url" : "http://mediamemo.allthingsd.com/20100906/site-builder-wetpaint-makes-one-for-itself-using-the-demand-media-playbook/", "source_text" : null, "source_description" : "All Things D", "stoneable_type" : "Company", "stoned_value" : null, "stoned_value_type" : null, "stoned_acquirer" : null, "stoneable" : { "name" : "Wetpaint", "permalink" : "wetpaint" } } ], "video_embeds" : [], "screenshots" : [ { "available_sizes" : [ [ [ 150, 86 ], "assets/images/resized/0016/0929/160929v2-max-150x150.png" ], [ [ 250, 143 ], "assets/images/resized/0016/0929/160929v2-max-250x250.png" ], [ [ 450, 258 ], "assets/images/resized/0016/0929/160929v2-max-450x450.png" ] ], "attribution" : null } ], "external_links" : [ { "external_url" : "http://www.geekwire.com/2011/rewind-ben-elowitz-wetpaint-ceo-building-type-media-company", "title" : "GeekWire interview: Rewind - Ben Elowitz, Wetpaint CEO, on building a new type of media company" }, { "external_url" : "http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/17/search-and-social-how-two-will-soon-become-one/", "title" : "Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in TechCrunch" }, { "external_url" : "http://allthingsd.com/20120516/what-to-expect-when-facebook-is-expecting-five-predictions-for-facebooks-first-public-year/", "title" : "Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in AllThingsD" }, { "external_url" : "http://adage.com/article/digitalnext/facebook-biggest-player-advertising-s-540-billion-world/235708/", "title" : "Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in AdAge" }, { "external_url" : "http://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-captures-14-percent-of-our-online-attention-but-only-4-percent-of-ad-spending-online-2012-6", "title" : "Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in Business Insider" }, { "external_url" : "http://allfacebook.com/wetpaint-media-data_b75963", "title" : "AllFacebook coverage of Wetpaint" }, { "external_url" : "http://adage.com/article/digital/celeb-site-wetpaint-shows-media-profit-facebook/237828/", "title" : "Profile of Wetpaint in Ad Age" }, { "external_url" : "http://allthingsd.com/20121018/how-to-boost-your-facebook-traffic-tips-and-tricks-from-wetpaint/", "title" : "Interview with Wetpaint CEO Ben Elowitz in All Things D" }, { "external_url" : "http://www.xconomy.com/seattle/2012/10/19/wetpaint-starts-licensing-its-facebook-based-media-distribution-tech/", "title" : "Profile of Wetpaint in Xconomy" } ], "partners" : [] }
```

Need your help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that `json.loads` expects a string, which it then decodes into a python object. As a solution, you have two possible options.

**Option 1**
Pass a file object to `json.load`:

```
tweets = json.load(input_file)
```

```
>>> import json
>>> import pprint
>>> tweets = json.load(open('file.json'))
>>> pprint.pprint(tweets)
{'_id': {'$oid': '52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8a'},
 'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 16,
                 'acquired_month': 12,
                 'acquired_year': 2013,
                 'acquiring_company': {'name': 'Viggle',
                                       'permalink': 'viggle'},
                 'price_amount': 30000000,
                 'price_currency_code': 'USD',
                 'source_description': ' Viggle Tries to Bulk Up Its Social '
                                       'TV Business by Buying Wetpaint',
                 'source_url': 'http://allthingsd.com/20131216/viggle-tries-to-bulk-up-its-social-tv-business-by-buying-wetpaint/?mod=atdtweet',
                 'term_code': 'cash_and_stock'},
 'acquisitions': [],
 'alias_list': '',
 'blog_feed_url': 'http://digitalquarters.net/feed/',
 'blog_url': 'http://digitalquarters.net/',
 'category_code': 'web',
 'competitions': [{'competitor': {'name': 'Wikia', 'permalink': 'wikia'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'JotSpot', 'permalink': 'jotspot'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'Socialtext',
                                  'permalink': 'socialtext'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'Ning by Glam Media',
                                  'permalink': 'ning'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'Soceeo', 'permalink': 'soceeo'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'Yola', 'permalink': 'yola'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'SocialGO',
                                  'permalink': 'socialgo'}},
                  {'competitor': {'name': 'IslamNor',
                                  'permalink': 'islamnor'}}],
 'created_at': {'$date': 1180075887000},
 'crunchbase_url': 'http://www.crunchbase.com/company/wetpaint',
 'deadpooled_year': 1,
 'description': 'Technology Platform Company',
 'email_address': 'info@wetpaint.com',
 'external_links': [{'external_url': 'http://www.geekwire.com/2011/rewind-ben-elowitz-wetpaint-ceo-building-type-media-company',
                     'title': 'GeekWire interview: Rewind - Ben Elowitz, '
                              'Wetpaint CEO, on building a new type of '
                              'media company'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/17/search-and-social-how-two-will-soon-become-one/',
                     'title': 'Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in TechCrunch'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://allthingsd.com/20120516/what-to-expect-when-facebook-is-expecting-five-predictions-for-facebooks-first-public-year/',
                     'title': 'Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in AllThingsD'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://adage.com/article/digitalnext/facebook-biggest-player-advertising-s-540-billion-world/235708/',
                     'title': 'Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in AdAge'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-captures-14-percent-of-our-online-attention-but-only-4-percent-of-ad-spending-online-2012-6',
                     'title': 'Guest post by CEO Ben Elowitz in Business '
                              'Insider'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://allfacebook.com/wetpaint-media-data_b75963',
                     'title': 'AllFacebook coverage of Wetpaint'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://adage.com/article/digital/celeb-site-wetpaint-shows-media-profit-facebook/237828/',
                     'title': 'Profile of Wetpaint in Ad Age'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://allthingsd.com/20121018/how-to-boost-your-facebook-traffic-tips-and-tricks-from-wetpaint/',
                     'title': 'Interview with Wetpaint CEO Ben Elowitz in '
                              'All Things D'},
                    {'external_url': 'http://www.xconomy.com/seattle/2012/10/19/wetpaint-starts-licensing-its-facebook-based-media-distribution-tech/',
                     'title': 'Profile of Wetpaint in Xconomy'}],
 'founded_day': 17,
 'founded_month': 10,
 'founded_year': 2005,
 'funding_rounds': [{'funded_day': 1,
                     'funded_month': 10,
                     'funded_year': 2005,
                     'id': 888,
                     'investments': [{'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Frazier '
                                                                'Technology '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'frazier-technology-ventures'},
                                      'person': None},
                                     {'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Trinity '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'trinity-ventures'},
                                      'person': None}],
                     'raised_amount': 5250000,
                     'raised_currency_code': 'USD',
                     'round_code': 'a',
                     'source_description': '',
                     'source_url': 'http://seattlepi.nwsource.com/business/246734_wiki02.html'},
                    {'funded_day': 1,
                     'funded_month': 1,
                     'funded_year': 2007,
                     'id': 889,
                     'investments': [{'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Accel '
                                                                'Partners',
                                                        'permalink': 'accel-partners'},
                                      'person': None},
                                     {'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Frazier '
                                                                'Technology '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'frazier-technology-ventures'},
                                      'person': None},
                                     {'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Trinity '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'trinity-ventures'},
                                      'person': None}],
                     'raised_amount': 9500000,
                     'raised_currency_code': 'USD',
                     'round_code': 'b',
                     'source_description': '',
                     'source_url': 'http://pulse2.com/2007/01/09/wiki-builder-website-wetpaint-welcomes-95m-funding/'},
                    {'funded_day': 19,
                     'funded_month': 5,
                     'funded_year': 2008,
                     'id': 2312,
                     'investments': [{'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'DAG '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'dag-ventures'},
                                      'person': None},
                                     {'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Accel '
                                                                'Partners',
                                                        'permalink': 'accel-partners'},
                                      'person': None},
                                     {'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Trinity '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'trinity-ventures'},
                                      'person': None},
                                     {'company': None,
                                      'financial_org': {'name': 'Frazier '
                                                                'Technology '
                                                                'Ventures',
                                                        'permalink': 'frazier-technology-ventures'},
                                      'person': None}],
                     'raised_amount': 25000000,
                     'raised_currency_code': 'USD',
                     'round_code': 'c',
                     'source_description': 'Accel',
                     'source_url': 'http://www.accel.com/news/news_one_up.php?news_id=185'}],
 'homepage_url': 'http://wetpaint-inc.com',
 'image': {'available_sizes': [[[150, 75],
                                'assets/images/resized/0000/3604/3604v14-max-150x150.jpg'],
                               [[250, 125],
                                'assets/images/resized/0000/3604/3604v14-max-250x250.jpg'],
                               [[450, 225],
                                'assets/images/resized/0000/3604/3604v14-max-450x450.jpg']]},
 'investments': [],
 'milestones': [{'description': "Wetpaint named in Lead411's Hottest "
                                'Seattle Companies list',
                 'id': 5869,
                 'source_description': 'LEAD411 LAUNCHES "HOTTEST SEATTLE '
                                       'COMPANIES" AWARDS',
                 'source_text': None,
                 'source_url': 'http://www.lead411.com/seattle-companies.html',
                 'stoneable': {'name': 'Wetpaint', 'permalink': 'wetpaint'},
                 'stoneable_type': 'Company',
                 'stoned_acquirer': None,
                 'stoned_day': 8,
                 'stoned_month': 6,
                 'stoned_value': None,
                 'stoned_value_type': None,
                 'stoned_year': 2010},
                {'description': 'Site-Builder Wetpaint Makes One For '
                                'Itself, Using the Demand Media Playbook',
                 'id': 8702,
                 'source_description': 'All Things D',
                 'source_text': None,
                 'source_url': 'http://mediamemo.allthingsd.com/20100906/site-builder-wetpaint-makes-one-for-itself-using-the-demand-media-playbook/',
                 'stoneable': {'name': 'Wetpaint', 'permalink': 'wetpaint'},
                 'stoneable_type': 'Company',
                 'stoned_acquirer': None,
                 'stoned_day': 6,
                 'stoned_month': 9,
                 'stoned_value': None,
                 'stoned_value_type': None,
                 'stoned_year': 2010}],
 'name': 'Wetpaint',
 'number_of_employees': 47,
 'offices': [{'address1': '710 - 2nd Avenue',
              'address2': 'Suite 1100',
              'city': 'Seattle',
              'country_code': 'USA',
              'description': '',
              'latitude': 47.603122,
              'longitude': -122.333253,
              'state_code': 'WA',
              'zip_code': '98104'},
             {'address1': '270 Lafayette Street',
              'address2': 'Suite 505',
              'city': 'New York',
              'country_code': 'USA',
              'description': '',
              'latitude': 40.7237306,
              'longitude': -73.9964312,
              'state_code': 'NY',
              'zip_code': '10012'}],
 'overview': '<p>Wetpaint is a technology platform company that uses its '
             'proprietary state-of-the-art technology and expertise in '
             'social media to build and monetize audiences for digital '
             'publishers. Wetpaint’s own online property, Wetpaint '
             'Entertainment, an entertainment news site that attracts more '
             'than 12 million unique visitors monthly and has over 2 million '
             'Facebook fans, is a proof point to the company’s success in '
             'building and engaging audiences. Media companies can license '
             'Wetpaint’s platform which includes a dynamic playbook tailored '
             'to their individual needs and comprehensive training. Founded '
             'by Internet pioneer Ben Elowitz, and with offices in New York '
             'and Seattle, Wetpaint is backed by Accel Partners, the '
             'investors behind Facebook.</p>',
 'partners': [],
 'permalink': 'abc2',
 'phone_number': '206.859.6300',
 'products': [{'name': 'Wikison Wetpaint', 'permalink': 'wetpaint-wiki'},
              {'name': 'Wetpaint Social Distribution System',
               'permalink': 'wetpaint-social-distribution-system'}],
 'providerships': [],
 'relationships': [{'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Michael',
                               'last_name': 'Howell',
                               'permalink': 'michael-howell'},
                    'title': 'Co-Founder and VP, Social and Audience '
                             'Development'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Ben',
                               'last_name': 'Elowitz',
                               'permalink': 'ben-elowitz'},
                    'title': 'Co-Founder/CEO/Board of Directors'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Rob',
                               'last_name': 'Grady',
                               'permalink': 'rob-grady'},
                    'title': 'COO/Board of Directors'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Chris',
                               'last_name': 'Kollas',
                               'permalink': 'chris-kollas'},
                    'title': 'SVP, Strategy and Business Development'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Theresia',
                               'last_name': 'Ranzetta',
                               'permalink': 'theresia-ranzetta'},
                    'title': 'Board'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Gus',
                               'last_name': 'Tai',
                               'permalink': 'gus-tai'},
                    'title': 'Board Member'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Len',
                               'last_name': 'Jordan',
                               'permalink': 'len-jordan'},
                    'title': 'Board'},
                   {'is_past': False,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Alex',
                               'last_name': 'Weinstein',
                               'permalink': 'alex-weinstein'},
                    'title': 'Head of Technology and Product'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Bert',
                               'last_name': 'Hogue',
                               'permalink': 'bert-hogue'},
                    'title': 'CFO'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Brian',
                               'last_name': 'Watkins',
                               'permalink': 'brian-watkins'},
                    'title': 'CFO/ CRO'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Rob',
                               'last_name': 'Grady',
                               'permalink': 'rob-grady'},
                    'title': 'Senior Vice President, Marketing'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Werner',
                               'last_name': 'Koepf',
                               'permalink': 'werner-koepf'},
                    'title': 'VP, Technology and Product'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Kevin',
                               'last_name': 'Flaherty',
                               'permalink': 'kevin-flaherty'},
                    'title': 'VP Marketing'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Alex',
                               'last_name': 'Berg',
                               'permalink': 'alex-berg'},
                    'title': 'VP User Experience'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Steve',
                               'last_name': 'McQuade',
                               'permalink': 'steve-mcquade'},
                    'title': 'VP Engineering'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Susan',
                               'last_name': 'Mulcahy',
                               'permalink': 'susan-mulcahy'},
                    'title': 'Executive Editor'},
                   {'is_past': True,
                    'person': {'first_name': 'Chris',
                               'last_name': 'Kollas',
                               'permalink': 'chris-kollas'},
                    'title': 'VP Business Development'}],
 'screenshots': [{'attribution': None,
                  'available_sizes': [[[150, 86],
                                       'assets/images/resized/0016/0929/160929v2-max-150x150.png'],
                                      [[250, 143],
                                       'assets/images/resized/0016/0929/160929v2-max-250x250.png'],
                                      [[450, 258],
                                       'assets/images/resized/0016/0929/160929v2-max-450x450.png']]}],
 'tag_list': 'wiki, seattle, elowitz, media-industry, media-platform, '
             'social-distribution-system',
 'total_money_raised': '$39.8M',
 'twitter_username': 'BachelrWetpaint',
 'updated_at': 'Sun Dec 08 07:15:44 UTC 2013',
 'video_embeds': []}
>>>
>>> list(tweets.keys())
['overview', 'acquisition', 'offices', 'crunchbase_url', 'founded_month', 'blog_feed_url', 'image', 'investments', 'partners', 'twitter_username', 'category_code', 'milestones', 'permalink', 'homepage_url', 'competitions', 'screenshots', 'founded_year', 'funding_rounds', 'number_of_employees', 'video_embeds', '_id', 'providerships', 'relationships', 'name', 'deadpooled_year', 'phone_number', 'products', 'acquisitions', 'created_at', 'email_address', 'blog_url', 'external_links', 'description', 'tag_list', 'updated_at', 'total_money_raised', 'alias_list', 'founded_day']
```

---

**Option 2**
Pass a string to `json.loads`:

```
tweets = json.loads(input_file.read())
```

Comment: I understand. thank you for your response. both the above options are working. when i display the keys i get only the following keys:

Comment: [u'category_code', u'crunchbase_url', u'video_embeds', u'overview', u'image', u'updated_at', u'funding_rounds', u'total_money_raised', u'email_address', u'alias_list', u'relationships', u'partners', u'screenshots', u'founded_day', u'competitions', u'blog_feed_url', u'providerships', u'offices', u'phone_number', u'description', u'deadpooled_year', u'twitter_username', u'milestones', u'external_links',

Comment: u'number_of_employees', u'founded_year', u'founded_month', u'acquisitions', u'permalink', u'_id', u'name', u'created_at', u'homepage_url', u'products', u'blog_url', u'tag_list', u'investments', u'acquisition']

Comment: @Ravi So, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Ravi Can you open another question? It seems to be unrelated to `json.load`, so.

Comment: Err, I don't know if you realised but your JSON is nested, so many keys are inside the top level keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tweets = json.loads(input_file)
```

You wanted `json.loads(input_file.read())`

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your response. but, some of the json keys are missing. don't know why?

Comment: [u'category_code', u'crunchbase_url', u'video_embeds', u'overview', u'image', u'updated_at', u'funding_rounds', u'total_money_raised', u'email_address', u'alias_list', u'relationships', u'partners', u'screenshots', u'founded_day', u'competitions', u'blog_feed_url', u'providerships', u'offices', u'phone_number', u'description', u'deadpooled_year', u'twitter_username', u'milestones', u'external_links',

Comment: u'number_of_employees', u'founded_year', u'founded_month', u'acquisitions', u'permalink', u'_id', u'name', u'created_at', u'homepage_url', u'products', u'blog_url', u'tag_list', u'investments', u'acquisition']